# Просмотр истории git другого проекта

Tags: git

Позволяет ли git просматривать историю других проектов?

цель: отправить curl в репозиторий передав git команду (например git log)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20055398/4827341

Answer (score 0):

Git API позволяет посмотреть коммиты репозитория, что я думаю равноценно git log.

[Документация к методу](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)

Comment: Это апи github, для других систем (gitlab/stash) не подойдет

Comment: Дайте тогда конкретики больше в вопрос. 
У ГИТлаба есть очень похожее АПИ, и там есть метод для получения коммитов. Про stash не знаю.

Comment: интересует gitlab

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html

Comment: то что апи позволяет посмотреть коммиты репозитория, не совсем то что я имел ввиду, я имел ввиду что можно не только git log, но и `git log 1111111...2222222 --merges --oneline --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]'
` в таком формате, т.е. я кидаю в репозиторий  git команду, и мне приходит результат

Comment: @RuslanGorbunov `git clone` а затем все что хотите - такой вариант чем не устраивает?

Comment: Сначала выкачать проект в другой проект и так смотреть? Не устраивает то что проект который придется клонить очень "тяжелый" и будет теряться много времени

Comment: Всегда можно добавить remote и подкачивать переодически. Да, индекс будет суммарным, но зато всё, что вы хотите будет делаться локально.